# decode json syntax with php

Tags: php, json

I have a problem with json_decode. I can not find the right syntax to retrieve the title in the following json :

```
 {
  "name": "Emission",
  "count": 18,
  "lastsuccess": "Thu Apr 03 2014 09:03:36 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
  "results": {
    "Bourdin Direct": [
      {
        "Titre": {
        "href": "http://www.channel.com/video/",
        "text": "The TV SHOW"
        },
        "Date": "31/03/2014",
        "Duree": {
        "href": "http://www.channel.com/187457/",
        "text": "19:06"
        },
      },
      {
        "Titre": {
        "href": "http://www.channel.com/video/theshow/",
        "text": "The title"
        },
        "Date": "28/03/2014",
        "Duree": {
        "href": "http://www.channel.com/video/28-03-186929/",
        "text": "19:42"
        },
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For now, i have that :

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->results as $aArticle) {

$titre = $aArticle->Titre;

}
```

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: What's the wrong with your code? What is the result?

Comment: I dont think its a valid json.. u have some extra `,` http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Tip: once you decode it isn't JSON any more, it's a PHP object. `print_r()` the object to view its structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your "results" data is not in proper json format.

Try this format, it's working

> {   "name": "Emission",   "count": 18,   "lastsuccess": "Thu Apr 03
>   2014 09:03:36 GMT+0000 (UTC)",   "results":{"Bourdin
>   Direct":[{"Titre":{"href":["http://www.channel.com/video/"],"text":["The
>   TV
>   SHOW"]},"Date":["31/03/2014"]},{"Titre":{"href":["http://www.channel.com/video/"],"text":["The
>   TV SHOW"]},"Date":["31/03/2014"]}]} }

```
   $json = file_get_contents($url);  
   $data = json_decode($json, true); 
   foreach ($data[results] as $k => $aArticle) {    
    $titre = $aArticle[0]['Titre']["href"]; 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But it seems that my problem is not because of the Json format. I have edited it for this question, and maybe, i have made some mistakes. But even with the complete unedited Json, i still can't grab each titles. I have copy paste the complete json here : http://jsfiddle.net/yYF6H/

Comment: yes, i got ur answer, Try this $data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($data[results] as $k => $aArticle) {
 $titre = $aArticle[0]['Titre']["href"];
}

Comment: Thanks ! Now, the title is grab, but only for the first node. Do I have to add a i++ , for having $titre = $aArticle[1]['Titre']["text"];, and $titre = $aArticle[2]['Titre']["text"]; etc in a foreach ?

Comment: Yes u can add i++ or just add another foreach loop inside $data[results] as foreach ($data[results] as $k => $aArticle) { foreach($aArticle as $v){ print_r($v['Titre']["text"]); } }

Answer (score 0):

Try using var_dump()

[Example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
var_dump(json_decode($json_array));
var_dump(json_decode($json_array, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$titre = $aArticle->Titre->text;
```

Comment: Some prose would be nice.